# Is there a way to use CSS or Ruby to auto-split each block calls into columns?

Tags: css, ruby

I'm attempting to clear up the view for an old app that lists the names of former clients that have used particular buses. This is what it looked like:

```
    <div id="foo_list" style="display: none;">
        <div id="page_title"><h2>FOO</h2></div>
              <p class="ps20">Happy Foos who used our buses:</p>
                <div class="ps20">
                  <div class="grid_3 ps20">
                        <ul class="square_list">
                          <li>FOO1</li>
                          <li>FOO2 ETC... up to 10</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid_3">
                        <ul class="square_list">
                          <li>FOO1</li>
                          <li>FOO2 ETC... up to 10</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="float_l">
                        <ul class="square_list">
                          <li>FOO1</li>
                          <li>FOO2 ETC... up to 10</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I've extracted all the FOO-info and put it into our database and I'm using an each block to call the FOOs, but I don't know how to do that and keep the same format of three columns. Right now I'm just have one long column. Is there anyway to write some CSS that if the number of FOOs exceeds 10 that it will equally split the each block into 2 columns (example: 11 FOOs into 2 columns of 6 and 5), and if it exceeds 20 to split into 3 equal-as-possible columns? Or is this a Ruby solution? Or both?

This is what I've reduced it to, what I'm currently working with:

```
        <div id="foo_list" style="display: none;">
          <div id="page_title"><h2>FOO</h2></div>
            <p class="ps20">Happy Foos who used our buses:</p>
                <div class="ps20">
                   <ul class="square_list">
                        <% @bus.foos.each do | foo | %>  
                            <li><%= foo.name %></li>
                        <% end %>
                    </ul>
                </div>
             </div>
```

Comment: I'm unclear on what is going to be a column and what it's outermost element would be.  I see that you removed the original `<ul>` containing divs.

Comment: Just put all of those info blocks into an unordered (or ordered, if that makes more sense) list, and then float the list items or display them as `inline-block` (only if you need no list bullets/numbering), and give them a percentage width of a little less than 33% (and maybe use `box-sizing: border-box` additionally if you want to use paddings/borders on them). And don't forget to eliminate default margins/paddings of list and LI, or overwrite them with values that make sense in this layout.

Answer (score 0):

Rails' in_groups will do it on the ruby side.

http://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups

```
%w(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10).in_groups(3) {|group| p group}
["1", "2", "3", "4"]
["5", "6", "7", nil]
["8", "9", "10", nil]
```